# How to logout of Intellij's TeamCity plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, teamcity

I've logged into the TeamCity plugin for Intellij IDEA 13.1 using my TeamCity admin credentials, which are shared amongst my team.  I'd like to login using my own account so I can configure my watches, but I can't work out how to log out of the plugin.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tiny little icon in the very bottom right of the IntelliJ window (for me it's next to the lock icon for toggling read-only mode in the current buffer) that allows logout.